# Android app for tracking location to server

Tags: android, api, gps

I'm looking for an app (android) that send my location to a server for processing.

Basically I want to write a server that does stuff when I get to certain locations, but I don't want to write an app myself.

Comment: Must it be free? Must it be licensed for commercial use?

Comment: Free yes, commercial use no

Comment: Must it be configurable? If so, how? E.g configure how often it sends your location, send only if connected by wifi, not SIM card, send only by `HTTP POST`, not `HTTP GET`, etc, etc

Comment: Are you intending to track only a single user, or multiple? (this doesn't affect the app which you seek, but it has implications for @Steve's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could give [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) *If this then that*, a go - it is an Android/iOS app that lets you construct or download "recipes" that tell your phone to perform specific actions based on events such as entering or leaving in a specific location.

The App is free from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt) but you might, of course, incur data charges from your phone company.

Answer (score 0):

The Android app [TrackMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=LEM.TrackMe) when installed can be configured to forward data to your own server. The web software is also provided [here](http://www.luisespinosa.com/trackme_eng.html) if you would like to host it for viewing. The app alone will allow you to save the GPS data to your server for use in your own projects though.